# Cordova, ajax cross-domain calls works using jQuery but not using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cors, web-worker

My config.xml has the "Domain Access" set to "*".
I don't have the possibility to change remote server's headers (it's an hardware device).
My cross-domain jQuery.ajax calls works well.
But if i make the same calls using XMLHttpRequest they don't work! (i'm switching from jQuery to XHR because i need to put ajax into a web worker).

I'm using this function:

```
myapp.ajax=function(){
    var o = arguments[0]||{},
        url = o.url||null,
        cache = o.cache||true,
        timeout = o.timeout||0,
        callback = arguments[1]||function(){}
    ;
    if(!url)return null;
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.timeout = timeout;

    var urlToCall=url;
    if(!cache){
        urlToCall += urlToCall.indexOf('?')==-1 ? '?' : '&' ;
        urlToCall += '_=' + Date.now() ;
    }

    myRequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (myRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (myRequest.status == 200)    {
            callback(myRequest.responseText,'success',myRequest);
        } else {
            callback(myRequest,'error',myRequest.statusText);
        }
      }
    }

    myRequest.open("GET",urlToCall,true);
    myRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    myRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    myRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD");
    myRequest.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess (for lack of detail about how, exactly, it's not working) is that, since you are loading the worker as a Blob (I guess using `createObjectURL` from a Blob and passing the output to the `Worker` constructor), CORS would fail regardless of any headers, since it's not enabled for the `blob:` protocol.

Try loading the worker as a separate file, via http(s), and see what happens.